# Why does elrepo have nosrc instead of src packages for kernel-lt?

Tags: centos7

I see that elrepo only provides nosrc and not src packages for their kernel-lt but I don't understand their rational and nor have I been able to find it by searching.

Does anyone know the reason and where to look for documentation about it?

Answer (score 0):

According to the elrepo community this is done to avoid needless duplication

> if I were to guess I'd say mere size and the fact that the original is
> available in any kernel mirror. there is no benefit in duplicating that
> on the ElRepo's mirrors.
> To expand on what wolfy said, what is not included in our "nosrc" SRPM
> is the original linux code. In your case,
> http://mirrors.coreix.net/elrepo-archive-archive/kernel/el7/SRPMS/kernel-lt-4.4.236-1.el7.elrepo.nosrc.rpm
> and
> https://cdn.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/v4.x/linux-4.4.236.tar.xz